# How can I create a repeating linear background pinstripe effect?

Tags: html, css

I have tried this but it does not give the effect I want.

```
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 0, #222, #111 5px, #333 1px);
```

What I would like is to have the background be #222 and then every 5px going down the page I would like to have a 1px height horizontal line that is #333 color. I keep trying different combinations but I can't get it to work. Note this is just needed 
for modern IE9+ browsers.

Comment: Try this : `repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, #333, #222 5px)`

Comment: `repeating-linear-gradient(0, #222, #222 5px, #333 5px, #333 6px);` should work for you ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If you don't mind can you explain how they produce the 1px height line. I find the way the parameters are is a bit confused. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might be the simplest method.

```css
 body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #fff;
   background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 4px, #f00 5px, transparent 5px);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the doc about repeating-linear-gradient?

If you try the example they give, you get something that works fine... Just go to this link and read :

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient

Here is their example :

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, red 5px, white 5px, white 10px);
```

Go to this fiddle, seems like it's working fine...

http://jsfiddle.net/2o3ehav1/4/

Edit : vertical with your colors : http://jsfiddle.net/2o3ehav1/19/

(just try to edit your "pixel sizes")

Hope it helps! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this?

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(0, transparent, transparent 4px, #333 5px, transparent 5px);
background-color: #222;
```